# Expected value of the exponential of a normal-lognormal mixture in the special case where the correlation between the normal and lognormal r.v.s is 1

Tags: probability

Is there any way of analytically determining the expected value of $Z=e^{\alpha X e^{\beta X}}$, where $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ and $\alpha,\beta$ are known constants?

**A couple of the methods I tried:**

I tried evaluating the integral of $Z$ against the pdf of $X$ directly without managing to achieve much.
$$
E[Z]=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt 2\pi}e^{\alpha x e^{\beta x}-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx.
$$

Among others (which look even less neat in terms of outcome), I tried the substitution $y=e^x$, s.t. $dy=y dx$, to yield
$$
E[Z]=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt 2\pi}y^{1+\alpha y^\beta}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\log y)^2}dy.
$$

Noting that
$$
e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\log y)^2}=e^{\log (y^{-\frac{1}{2} \log y})}=y^{-\frac{1}{2} \log y}
$$

That "simplifies" the integral to
$$
E[Z]=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt 2\pi}y^{1+\alpha y^\beta-\frac{1}{2} \log y}dy,
$$
which I wasn't able to transform into anything I could evaluate.

One more interesting route I tried was to consider the variable $Y=\alpha Xe^{\beta X}$ and perform a Taylor expansion on $Z=e^Y$:
$$
E[Z]=E[e^Y]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E[\frac{1}{n!}Y^n]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha ^n}{n!}E[X^ne^{n\beta X}]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha ^n}{n!}E[\frac{1}{n^n}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial \beta^n} e^{n\beta X}]=
$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha ^n}{n! n^n}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial \beta^n}E[ e^{n\beta X}]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha ^n}{n! n^n}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial \beta^n}e^{\frac{1}{2}n^2\beta^2}$$

At which point I got lost in the algebra trying to simplify this expression into a manageable infinite sum.

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, otherwise the question will attract downvotes.  According to [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1) this puts answerers in an awkward position too since we are not allowed to answer questions that don't meet the quality standards of the MSE.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I have gone through pages of helpless algebra without being able to make any progress. I have tried to directly evaluate the integral of $Z$ against the p.d.f. of $X$ but I can't seem to be able to find a tractable form of the integrand. Apologies for not having added any of those details but my work was going round in circles without any progress.

Comment: In such cases, explain what integration methods you have tried and why they failed, e.g. you performed the substituting $t=\cdots$ but this led to a more difficult looking integral...etc.  I'm sure there are people interested in the question that will answer if they can but our hands are tied until you add more to your post.

Comment: I have added more information as you rightfully pointed out. I am new to the site so I apologize if the initial question wasn't sufficiently detailed in terms of my attempts to solve it. I hope this new version isn't downvoted as I am really looking to abide by the community standards.